# ssh + pipe: CTRL-C should also terminate remote command

Tags: ssh, pipe

I need to run a command remote, so i start it via ssh. If i use CTRL-C, both the local ssh client and the remote command is terminated. Good.

For some reason i need to pipe some data to the remote, so my command looks like this:

```
ssh user@remote "wc -c; sleep 10000" < test.data
```

The data is received and processed. But if i now press CTRL-C, only the local command (the ssh client) is terminated.

How to solve this problem? (the requirement is: sending data to remote, execute a command remote using this data. The whole thing should be cleanly interruptable with CTRL-C)

In case it would be helpful: STDIN of the remote can be closed after "wc". Unfortunately my attempts with closing stdin were not successful...

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -t` or `ssh -t -t` as per https://stackoverflow.com/q/331642 ?

Comment: Siguza: Yes i did: '-t' is ignored (warning because of pipe) and '-tt' breaks the pipe (data is sent to stdout , wc does not receive data)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which is more a hack. So i am still interested in a better way...

```
ssh user@remote "
  #start background subshell to cleanly stop processes after pressing
  #CTRL-C on ssh's client side...
  SHPID=\$\$;
  (
    while sleep 1
    do
      PP=\$SHPID; 
      while [[ \$PP -gt 1 ]]
      do 
        PP=\$(ps -o ppid= \$PP)
        ps -o cmd= \$PP
      done | grep -Eq '^/usr/sbin/sshd( |\$)'
      [[ \$? -ne 0 ]] && break
    done
    pkill -TERM -P \$SHPID
  ) &

  #the real command
  wc -c
  sleep 10000
"
```

The idea is to periodically check the process tree for the existence of a "/usr/sbin/sshd" process. If that doesn't exist anymore, kill all jobs "below" $SHPID